# Codeigniter Aliase not working in Views

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, web

I wrote a lot of code in codeigniter but I had to restructure my database column prefixes and when I use join queries to join some of my tables in my model's queries there is some tables in one query that have the same id column , I used Alias 'As alias1' for a table name, and model runs successfully without problem

but when I pass the `$q = $this->db->get()` variable to my controller and then pass it to my view and iterate it like this :

```
foreach($q->result() as $res)
   echo $res->alias1.id;
```

php errors that unknown `$alias1.id` but I declared `alias1` for one of my tables.

whats the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: can you please write what result you get in `$q`

Comment: you question does not  have enough information. Please write your model(the query) and view

Answer (score 1):

When you do `->result()`, CI will build an array of objects.
Each column declared in your select will be an object member. However, the aliases are not preserved.

It means that `SELECT alias.field` will be converted as `$obj->field` not `$obj->alias.field`.

If you have two fields which have the same name, set an alias inside your `SELECT` clause

```
$this->db->select("alias1.field as myfield, alisas2.field as myotherfield");
```

Then you will be able to get them with `$obj->myfield` and `$obj->myotherfield`

Comment: but is this mean that there isn't any way to use alias directly in views?

Comment: Yes you can, that's what I try to explain in the second part of my answer and seting aliases in the select clause.